# Problem when binding IP addresses with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

To begin with, there are really a lot of questions identical to this one. I've looked at a lot of them and I still have a problem.

I wanted to bind multiple IP addresses in the configuration file but when I restart the `mongod` service, it encounters an error (this is only the case when I try to bind multiple addresses).

I tried all the proposed formats, such as :

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1 #Method given by the official documentation
bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1
bindIp: [127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1]
bindIp: [127.0.01, 127.0.0.0.1]
```

**EDIT: I tried `bindIp: 127.0.0.0.1,localhost` and it works. So we can maybe discard the format track but how can I bind the IP of my home network?**

systemctl error : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9T8T3zZT9T/
logs: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bDfdkP58pq/

If anyone has a solution to this problem, I'll take it. I also tried to delete the sockets files.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is its complain? We have the first and second of your tries in our currently working configurations (MongoDB 3.6, 4.0, and 4.2).

Comment: Hello, the service failed to launch. (https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9T8T3zZT9T/)

Comment: And here are the logs: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bDfdkP58pq/ (sorry for double posting, having issues with my connection so I wasn't able to edit my previous comment)

Comment: Are you sure about this IP belonging to this machine (run `ifconfig`)? If yes, are you sure there is not another program listening on port 27017 of that IP (run `netstat -ntlp`)? If yes again, does it work if you configure mongodb to only listen on that non-localhost IP?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I thought they were the IPs that have the right to authenticate when in fact they are the IPs on which the server is listening. Sorry for the inconvenience, but it seems that most of the other topics were also wrong. Maybe it should be specified on the documentation if it is not already the case.Thank you for your help and responsiveness.

Comment: Good to hear it's solved! If you want to harden the access to your DB, you must limit it from your firewall. MongoDB doesn't have a host-based authentication tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

> bindIp: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1

You cannot bind to the same IP twice.

Comment: This is just an example

Comment: @ookenos Please provide your example as accurate as possible. To troubleshoot your problem, the case that it happens to you really matters!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was wrong all along.

The IP addresses entered after `bindIp` are NOT the addresses that are allowed to connect to the database.

In fact, they are the IP addresses that the server will listen on.

By the way, if you want to be protected, you should enable [Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) if you don't already do so.